# What GUI libraries does OpenOffice use?

Tags: user-interface, openoffice.org

Can someone please tell me what GUI libraries does OpenOffice use?  The UI on Windows and Linux look surprising similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VCL, or Visual Components Library is the responsible module for widgets (windowing, buttons, controls..) operating system abstraction, including basic rendering (e.g. the output device). More information can be here: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/VCL.